# "error: forward reference extends over definition of variable counter"

Tags: scala, apache-spark, iteration

I have some flight/passenger data and I am trying to find the maximum number of countries a passenger has been to BEFORE going to UK.

I have narrowed down the problem to a particular case to keep it simple.

for Passenger A

`val ts = List("il", "ar", "ca", "bm", "au", "jo", "uk", "jo", "th", "uk", "ca", "cn", "sg", "il")`

My approach was to loop through the list ts (short for travel sequence).
* when the value != "uk" then counter goes up by 1
* once we reach a case where value = "uk" then store that counter value into run_length and then reset the counter. 
* once we have iterated through the whole list, we should the find the max of run_length.

This should in theory give the maximum places a passenger has been before they went to the UK.

However I get an error in my code.

```
import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer

var counter = 0
var runs: ArrayBuffer[Int] = ArrayBuffer()
val ts = List("il", "ar", "ca", "bm", "au", "jo", "uk", "jo", "th", "uk", "ca", "cn", "sg", "il")


for (i <- ts){
    if (i != "uk"){
        counter += 1
    }
    else {
        runs += counter
        var counter = 0
    }
}

val max_run = runs.max
println(max_run)
```

I get an error:

```
<console>:38: error: forward reference extends over definition of variable counter 
     runs += counter
```

I was expecting to get the value 6 because the max number of elements before "uk" is 6.

I am new to Scala (literally only been doing it for 2 days so far). Any help on resolving this will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it for you:

```
import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer

var counter = 0
var runs: ArrayBuffer[Int] = ArrayBuffer()
val ts = List("il", "ar", "ca", "bm", "au", "jo", "uk", "jo", "th", "uk", "ca", "cn", "sg", "il")


for (i <- ts){
    if (i != "uk"){
        counter += 1
    }
    else {
        runs += counter
        counter = 0 // <= this line is the fix
    }
}

val max_run = runs.max
println(max_run)
```

Comment: To elaborate on @Gsquare's answer, `var counter = 0` defines a new `counter` variable in that scope.  The forward reference occurs because you referred to it in the previous line.

Comment: Thanks so much! Really appreciate the help. Thanks for the explanation.